# iPhone: how to see if GPS is working

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, gps

Is there a way where I can see if GPS is working? Or what the location service is using right now and why it is not using GPS?

(Because the location service has become very inaccurate after a recent jailbreak I did and I was wondering how I can check if it is really not working anymore or if I just had bad luck.)

Comment: I'm guessing turning off WiFi, standing outside and opening up Maps.app would do the trick, if it correctly displays where you are it works, if it doesn't... it doesn't.

Comment: @Ryan: Put your comment in an answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing turning off WiFi, standing outside and opening up Maps.app would do the trick, if it correctly displays where you are it works, if it doesn't... it doesn't.

Comment: It does but it stays inaccurate. How do I know if that means that I just don't have a GPS signal, the GPS signal is bad or GPS is not working?

Comment: is it finding your general area but the blue dot has a larger blue circle around it?

Comment: Exactly. In some situations, it is becoming smaller and smaller but I think I have never seen it going away since then. But how can I know if it is just a bad/no GPS signal or if GPS is really not working at all?

Comment: i am not a GPS expert but if it is giving you the correct general area then it is working but has a weak signal.  if it is placing you in an entirely different city, county, state, country then you may have an issue with it.

Comment: It would put me into the right street even if GPS is not working, just based on the other location services (mobile cellular data, WLAN data).